# Form with checkbox destinations

Tags: php, forms

I have a problem. I did a form with i can choose who goes it with "checkbox"

The problem is the message is just going to the 2nd destiantion (2nd checkbox), and ignore the other checked.

Can anybody help? Thks

exemple of my code:

...(begining)...

`<form action="<?$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">`

...(somewhere in the form)...

`<input type="checkbox" name="emailto" id="emailto1" value="mail@xxx.com">MV
<input type="checkbox" name="emailto" id="emailto2" value="mail@xxx.com">`

...(before all form)...

`<?
if ($_POST['submit']){`

`$titulo = "** BRIEF **";
$sender = "BRIEF<sender@xxx.com>";
$to = $_POST ['emailto']; 
$reply = "sender@xxx.com";`

`$mensagem = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'
'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
</head>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>";`

`mail($to, $titulo, $mensagem,"From:$sender\r\nReply-to:$reply\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
echo "<b><font face='Verdana' color='#C10000' size='2' align='center'>Dados enviados com sucesso.</b></font>";
    }
?>`

...

`

Comment: what do you get in $_POST['emailto'] ?

Comment: Could you clarifiy your problem a bit better please? It's quite hard to understand. You have multiple checkboxes and want all values from them and not just a single (the last) one?

Comment: my question is incomplete because was ignored some parts... i will try to explain witout copy past of code:

in form, i put 2 checkbox, with name="emailto" and values"email destination".

the problem is ... when i send the form online, it goes only to 1 recepient of checkbox, it ignores the first checkbox.

Comment: i have edited the question. (sorry i'm a noob in this things) :) Can u help? Thks.

Comment: Can you publish your html somewhere else? I guess you handle checkboxes values badly.

Comment: ...i edited again the question with more information. maybe helps :)

Answer (score 0):

write `name="emailto[]"`  and see the data

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST['emailto']);
```

it's an array of email

Comment: didin't works ... :( ...i edited again the question with more information. maybe helps :)

Comment: u didn't change the `name` value of `checkbox` to `emailto[]`

Comment: i did, but it dint work, so i put the original again. With this example what do i have to do? thks again

Answer (score 0):

As for as I have understood your problem you should work with array. Changed the names of your checkboxes with array like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="emailto[]" id="emailto1" value="xxx@xx.com">
<span class="font_bold_01">PG + MV    
<input type="checkbox" name="emailto[]" id="emailto2" value="xxx@xx.com">
PG + MV + VC
```

On other hand use loop to get all checked values. Hope it is the answer